# AngularJS factory and controller code, not producing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When the below code is run nothing shows in my console to indicate anything went wrong, but as you can see in listService it's alerting withing the results, but the alert shows as "undefined".

I'm ultimately trying to get it to run a repeat to list all the Organizations on the view.  Any help is appreciated!!

Here is my factory.

```js
app.factory("listService", ["$rootScope", "$http", "$location", "$routeParams",
    function($rootScope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
        var siteURL = "jdfyhgyjdfghyjdgfyhkjyhjk";
        var svc = {};
        var data = null;

        svc.getListItems = function(listName) {
            $http({
                url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items",
                method: "GET",
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function(response, status, headers, config) {
                    data = response.data.d.results;
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(response, status, headers, config) {
                    $rootScope.error = status;
                }
            });
        }
        return svc;
    }
]);
```

Here is my controller.

```js
app.controller("readOrganizationsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$routeParams", "listService",
    function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, listService) {
        $scope.organizations = listService.getListItems('Organizations');
    }
]);
```

And lastly here is my view.

```js
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search organizations" data-ng-model="search" />
</div>
<table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="organization in organizations | filter:search" data-ng-click="editOrganization($index)">
            <td>{{organization.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <button data-ng-click="addOrganization()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Organization</button>
</div>
{{"Error:" + error}}
```

Comment: The `$http` service is not `jQuery.ajax`. Read [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after calling $http in controller you can easily get all your organizations from siteURL, here is working code: 
JS:

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'organizations.json',
                headers: {
                 withCredentials: true,
                 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                 },
                })
                .then(function successCallback(data) {
                    $scope.organizations = data.data;
                    console.log($scope.organizations)

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('error');
                });    
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="organization in organizations | filter:search" data-ng-click="editOrganization($index)">
            <td>{{organization.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aP7fLU1tfWwmZdCAYzIf?p=preview

Or, if you want to do it by factory, you can do it this way:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, factory) {

      factory.getOrganizations()
         .then(function(data){
            $scope.organizations = data.data;
                    console.log($scope.organizations)
         })
         .catch(function(){
         })
      });

app.factory('factory',function($http){
  return {
     getOrganizations: function(){
        return $http.get('organizations.json');
     }
  };
})
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UJUrTIGHGtjjccGAnHlk?p=preview

Comment: Why do you have `async: false`? It is a good thing that the $http service ignores that property.

Comment: @georgeawg hmm, yes you are right. I just copied it by accident from Darkmatter5 code

Comment: Awesome, but when I run it like this on SharePoint data it doesn't want to parse through the data because the returned result is not an array.

Comment: Disregard, I did "$scope.organizations = data.data.d.results;" and now it works.

Comment: @Darkmatter5 thumbs up!